I have ended up with two accounts on the Physics Stack Exchange. Can they be merged?
I created two accounts by accident, but would prefer to have only one.

Yes, you can merge your accounts. At the bottom of any page on the site, click "contact," then choose "account issue." Merging accounts is one of the account issues in the list.
